# The menu item disappear from the activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add menu item and it's icon, but the design result does not show the item's title and icon, What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your class and see again :

```java
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```